# What is the start symbol in this grammar?

Tags: parsing, tree

What is the start symbol?

Based on some research "**The start symbol we choose should allow the grammar to parse the most input sentences**"

Clearly < Var > is NOT a start symbol as it will parse least input sentences, then start symbol is < Var > or < Group > ?

```
 <Group> ::= [ <One>, <Group> ] | <One>
 <One>   ::= <Var> | ( <Group> )
 <Var>   ::= a | b | c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final (start?) symbol is also called an AXIOM.

It is always given explicitly. It should never be deduced. It is decided by the author of the grammar.